# Javascript error in generic handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In order to render enumerators to client side I use following code in .ashx file:

```js
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Common" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Xeleton.ModuleAccount.Core;
using Xeleton.ModuleBase.Core;

public class Common : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        context.Response.Write(SharedFunctionality.SerializeEnumerator<AccountType>());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This produces following output:

```js
AccountType={"Local":0,"Google":1,"Facebook":2,"Twitter":3};
```

All scripts and styles are bundled on the website so I provide this file in BundleConfig:

```js
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts").Include("~/Services/Common.ashx"));
}
```

Everything works fine, site is up and running.

When I deploy this application to server, I am getting following error in firebug console:

[image]

So I thought the bundle logic is reading the file and not executing and reading output. I build on my development machine in Release mode, but the error does not occur. The server is 2012R2 using IIS8.5

Answer (score 0):

You use bundles to bundle javascript or css files together not ashx files.

**snippet from BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
}
```

Then in your cshtml file you reference your bundle to include your javascript files into the generated html.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: The handler file returns a javascript file and I want it to be bundled and minified which is a reasonable approach in my opinion. Also, on my local machine it works fine. I wonder why it is not working on remote machine

Comment: Oh, it appears IIS isn't setup to pass processing of ashx files to ASP.NET.  So it's serving ashx files to your browser as is.  What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2 , IIS 8.5

Comment: In the IIS manager, under your web application, open Handler Mappings and make sure there's an entry for *.ashx.

Comment: Yes. Actually if I access  file directly, I receive desired result. Never mind, I included it separately in the page. Thanks a lot for your help and time.